# SSL_ERROR_SSL GCP Pub/Sub Error On Publish

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to publish a message to GCP Pub/Sub with the following python code. When trying to run the code I receive the error:

> Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL
> routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE VERIFY_FAILED

When creating a request I know you can do something like this

```
requests.get('https://example.com', verify=False)
```

and I also know I can set verify to false in clients I create in AWS but I'm not sure how I'd go about doing it in this case.

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from google.auth import jwt

#service account details
service_account_info = {}

audience = "https://pubsub.googleapis.com/google.pubsub.v1.Subscriber"

# TODO(developer)
project_id = "id"
topic_id = "my-topic"

credentials = jwt.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    service_account_info, audience=audience
)

# The same for the publisher, except that the "audience" claim needs to be adjusted
publisher_audience = "https://pubsub.googleapis.com/google.pubsub.v1.Publisher"

credentials_pub = credentials.with_claims(audience={publisher_audience})

publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(credentials=credentials_pub)
topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)

data = f"Message test"
# Data must be a bytestring
data = data.encode("utf-8")
# When you publish a message, the client returns a future.
future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data)
print(future.result())

print(f"Published messages to {topic_path}.")
```

Comment: Most likely your application's list of trusted root certificates needs to be updated. https://www.jhanley.com/curl-ssl-certificate-problem/

Comment: I tried the solutions on your article but they have not helped.